# Write for our blog! Q2 2013

Tags: discussion, blog

It's a new year and we've kind of slacked off on our Eschewmenical blog so far. But not any more.

We will handle topic selection later, but for now, I need four volunteers to commit to one post a month for all of the second quarter of this year (April-June). I'll write the intros like I have been and kick off the topics. But we need 4 people who are willing to write on 3 different topics that we can select when we get organized.

Ideally our 4 authors will have four different perspectives in the spirit of eschewmenicism.

I'd like to start publishing the second Monday in April. So please answer this post if you'd like to sign up.

If you've got any questions about how blog authorship works around here. Feel free to drop by our [blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2567/eschewmenical-blog-room).

***Our slate of authors for Q2 2013 is set. Look for a new sign up for Q3 coming in June.***

Comment: And of course, I'll continue to work as editor and backup publisher.

Comment: Can I continue my roll as elusive stand in author that never stands in?

Comment: @Caleb sure, there's a fifth week of April if you want to chime in on whatever we pick as the topic, though I wasn't planning on kicking us off until the second week so it was 4/month instead of trying to find an extra on the month we are doing the reboot.

Comment: @waxeagle: Sounds like you have a good plan. I'd stick to it for now. Maybe my half written Christmas rant will be finished for December 2013.

Comment: How long and how in-depth articles are you looking for? I might be interested in doing this

Comment: @SSumner we're pretty lenient on both length and depth. Ultimately we want quality posts that properly represent their perspective. Posts should be as long as they need to be, but there is no minimum or maximum length. As far as depth? I'd like us to be as in depth as possible, but sometimes topics and perspectives lend themselves to shallower analysis

Comment: Then I'm willing to write, but this month's I'll need a few weeks of lead time because school is pretty busy and I'll have to find time to do it. May-Jun wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SSumner maybe go ahead an post an answer then. I'd like to get our slate of authors selected so we can get a topic picked. You could probably go last in April if that would be helpful.

Comment: I've now closed author signups as we have the requisite 4. If someone sees an upcoming topic they want to post on please contact me through the blog room and we might be able to work something out.

Answer (score 9):

I'll keep writing (unless absolutely no one wants me to)

Comment: Here's a +1 that says at least this one person wants you to, so "absolutely no one" is off the table.

Answer (score 5):

I'd be willing to write, but I don't know that I could accurately represent any specific viewpoint.  At best, I could represent a "mutant conglomeration of denominational views that lean toward the hard-to-define Fundamentalist conservative Protestant, sprinkled with some ideas that are just out there".

In other words, I don't necessarily feel I could accurately represent a specific established view without straying into personal interpretation, but if you have something here and there that you think I might be able to contribute on, I'd be happy to contribute.

That said, if there aren't enough volunteers, count me in.  I always have an opinion.  ;-)

Comment: We don't necessarily need specific denominational view points, just people who are willing to take facets of different issues. We need people with opinions and it certainly sounds like you have them :).

Answer (score 4):

I would be willing to write something.

My perspective is probably more "generic liberal Protestant" than particularly denominational, though I am a member of a Presbyterian church. What comes through will depend on the topic. It would be nice to let my hair down a bit and write something more opinion-y than I usually do on this site.

No preference on dates; I could do an earlier or later one, or more than one, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I would be willing to write something.

My perspective is solidly Calvinistic, member of a Presbyterian (PCA) church.

As far as dates, for April, I'd prefer a later date, so as to have more time to prepare with school. May & June doesn't really matter, so long as it's not the first week of May.